# Key not loaded: Key<Frame> while POSTing source frame through ParseSetup in H2O API call

Tags: java, rest, api, curl, h2o

**My code:**

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:54321/3/ParseSetup --data 'source_frames=["/root/documents/my_file.csv"]'
```

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key not loaded: Key  at
>   water.api.ParseSetupHandler.guessSetup(ParseSetupHandler.java:31)

Help:

Could anyone help to resolve this? Am I missing any parameter?

Used H2O version: `h2o-3.10.0.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to open Flow (http://localhost:54321) in a browser, then start Firebug (or the equivalent in your browser of choice), and the network tab. Then do a file import from Flow, then the parse, and make a note of exactly what it is sending.

(Alternatively do the import from R or Python with a packet sniffer going, but that sounds like harder work.)

Did you do the /3/ImportFiles calls first?
(I actually see three calls: ImportFiles, ParseSetup, Parse.)

In my quick test I'm seeing the "nfs://" prefix on all the paths. Don't know if that is important.

But, my first guess would be that you should be using `--data-urlencode` instead of `--data`. Or manually URL-encode your data.

Comment: Thank you! I used '--data-urlencode' and "nfs://" prefix. It worked.

Comment: @user3117619 Great - that is useful to know. Thanks!