# "Error: Key not loaded" in h2o deployed through a K3s cluster, using python3 client

Tags: python-3.x, h2o, k3s

I can confirm the 3-replica cluster of h2o inside K3s is correctly deployed, as executing in the Python3 interpreter `h2o.init(ip="x.x.x.x")` works as expected. I followed the instructions noted here: https://www.h2o.ai/blog/running-h2o-cluster-on-a-kubernetes-cluster/

Nevertheless, I had to modify the `service.yaml` and comment out the line which says `clusterIP: None`, as K3s was complaining about something related to its inability to set the clusterIP to None. But even though, I can certify it is working correctly, and I am able to use an external IP to connect to the cluster.

If I try to load the dataset using the h2o cluster inside the K3s cluster using the exact same steps as described here http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html, this is the output that I get:

```
>>> train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")
...
h2o.exceptions.H2OResponseError: Server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Key not loaded: Key<Frame> https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv
  Request: POST /3/ParseSetup
    data: {'check_header': '0', 'source_frames': '["https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv"]'}
```

The same error occurs if I use the `h2o.upoad_file("x.csv")` method.

There is a clue about what may be happening here: [Key not loaded: Key<Frame> while POSTing source frame through ParseSetup in H2O API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543314/key-not-loaded-keyframe-while-posting-source-frame-through-parsesetup-in-h2o) but I am not using curl, and I can not find any parameter that could help me overcome this issue: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=import_file#h2o.import_file

I need to use the Python client inside the same K3s cluster due to different technical reasons, so I am not able to kick off nor Flow nor Firebug to know what may be happening.

I can confirm it is working correctly when I simply issue a `h2o.init()`, using the local Java instance.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried in different K3s clusters without success. I changed the `service.yaml` to a NodePort, and now this is the error traceback:

```
>>> train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")
...
h2o.exceptions.H2OResponseError: Server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Job is missing
  Request: GET /3/Jobs/$03010a2a016132d4ffffffff$_a2366be93ec99a78d7bc161de8c54d67
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have tried using different services (NodePort, LoadBalancer, ClusterIP) and none of them work. I also have tried using `Minikube` with the official image, and with a custom image made by me, without success. I suspect this is something related to either h2o itself, or the clustering between pods. I will keep digging and let's think there will be some gold in it.

**UPDATE 3:**

I also found out that the post about running H2O in Docker is really outdated https://www.h2o.ai/blog/h2o-docker/ nor is working the Dockerfile present at GitHub (I changed it to uncomment the ENTRYPOINT section without success): https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Dockerfile

Even though, I tried with the custom image I built for h2o-k8s and it is working seamlessly in pure Docker. I am wondering why it is still not working in K8s...

**UPDATE 4:**

I have tried modifying the environment variable called `H2O_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_DNS` without success.

In the meantime, the cluster started to be unavailable, that is, the `readinessProbe`'s would not successfully complete. No matter what I change now, it does not work.

I spinned up a K3d cluster in local to see what happened, and surprisingly, the `readinessProbe`'s were not failing, using `v3.30.0.6`. But now I started testing it with R instead of Python. I am glad I tried, because I may have pinpointed what was wrong. There is a version mismatch between the client and the server. So I updated accordingly the image to `v3.30.0.1`.

But now again, the `readinessProbe` is not working in my k3d cluster, so I am unable to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is working now. R client version `3.30.0.1` with server version `3.30.0.1`. Also tried with Python version `3.30.0.7` and server version `3.30.0.7` and it started working. Marvelous. The problem was caused by a version mismatch between the client and the server, as the python client was updated to `3.30.0.7` while the latest server for docker was `3.30.0.6`.

Comment: Did you always use matching client & server version, e.g. the failing 3.30.0.6 failed with 3.30.0.6 backend ?

Comment: Thank you, Pavel. That was the problem. Updated the answer accordingly